# How to group vertices by property list content

Tags: gremlin

In my graph, I have vertices that contain a property with a list cardinality. I'd like to group that vertices by the content of the list.

In this example graph:

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()
g.addV().
  property('name', 'v1').
  property(list, 'label', 'A').
  property(list, 'label', 'B')
g.addV().
  property('name', 'v2').
  property(list, 'label', 'B').
  property(list, 'label', 'C')
```

I've tried this query

```
g.V().group().by(properties('label')).by('name').unfold()
==>vp[label->A]=[v1]
==>vp[label->B]=[v2]
```

but it is what I expect : `A=[v1],B=[v1,v2],C=[v2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a nicer way to do this, but here's an option:

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').properties('label').
......1>   group().
......2>     by(value()).
......3>     by(select('a').by('name').fold()).
......4>   unfold()
==>A=[v1]
==>B=[v1, v2]
==>C=[v2]
```

I think that you need to iterate all of the `properties()` into `group()`, but the problem is that there is no way to reference the parent vertex to that property through Gremlin. It looks a bit nicer with a lambda:

```
gremlin> g.V().properties('label').group().by(value()).by({it.element().value('name')}).unfold()
==>A=[v1]
==>B=[v1, v2]
==>C=[v2]
```

but TinkerPop tends not to recommend that approach as it reduces your code portability.